# Preview changing lines I draw and adding text box

Tags: mac, preview

Why does the line I draw disappear and add a text box in preview?  I must've hit some keys to create this....I only want to draw a colored line.

Answer (score 1):

To draw a line in preview go to the Tools menu and select Annotate. Under the Annotate option is an option for a line. This will put a single line on your page.
You might have hit rectangle instead on line. I can't guess very well what you did wrong.